# being vs acting

Tags: difference, sentence-choice

Last time I saw him he was being weird. / Last time I saw him he was acting weird.

Do they mean the same thing? Could I use them interchangeably? Which one would native speakers be more inclined to use?

Answer (score 1):

One of the uses of the verb *to be* is *to act in a particular way*, so you could use *being weird* in colloquial speech.

Strictly speaking, *acting* needs an adverb rather than an adjective - *acting weirdly* or *acting strangely.*